# How can I render html page on a page instead of a popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When a user clicks on extension icon I need it to open a page that renders predefined HTML instead of a popup window with this HTML.
For popup window, I know that I need to use `browser_action.default_popup` in the manifest. What do I need to use for a page?

Comment: Remove "default_popup" and use chrome.browserAction.onClicked + chrome.tabs.create in your background script.

Comment: but how can I make this new tab render my HTML?

Comment: It's hard to answer a vague question, but there are multiple ways you can "render" HTML.